# Помогите исправить ошибку с библиотекой BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
link = soup.find().find('div', class_='styles_root__ti07r')
.find('a', class_='styles_poster__gJgwz styles_root__wgbNq')
.get('href')
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> AttributeError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\Education\Myself\parser.py", line 8, in 
> .find('a', class_='styles_poster__gJgwz styles_root__wgbNq')
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: link = soup.find().find('div', class_='styles_root__ti07r') Элемента DIV с указанным классом нет в бульёне, поэтому функция вернула NoneType, что часто используется в Python. Теперь к вам вопрос у объекта NoneType разве есть метод find?

Comment: извините неверный код написал,
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
soup.find('div', class_='styles_root__ti07r').find('a', class_='styles_poster__gJgwz styles_root__wgbNq').get('href')

Comment: А ошибка та же?)

Comment: {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.28.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'} вот что отправляет ваш код, сервер посмотрев на это б**дство, отправляет вам в ответе что фиг вам а не TOP250, сервер не хочет что бы ему роботы запросы посылали. Решение? Научите ваш код отправлять запросы так как это делает ваш браузер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так это должно выглядеть:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
link = soup.find_all('div', class_='styles_root__ti07r')
soup_href = BeautifulSoup(str(link), 'lxml')
list_a = soup_href.find_all('a', class_='styles_poster__gJgwz 
styles_root__wgbNq')
link_list = ['https://www.kinopoisk.ru/'+ link.get('href') for link in list_a]
```

link_list список с ссылками.
Но  проблема в том что через библиотеку request вы попадёте на страницу защиты в виде капчи. Код выше вы можете проверить сохранив код страницы просто в файл 'kino.txt'.  Я проверил ссылки вытаскивает. Чтобы обойти капчу вам нужно через браузер осуществлять вход, а затем уже запросы библиотеки request python. Подробности уже не помню, но гуглите, там есть модули которые это делают и инструкции. Вот версия если сохранить код страницы в текстовый файл:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

file_name = 'kino.txt'
text = open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
link = soup.find_all('div', class_='styles_root__ti07r')
soup_href = BeautifulSoup(str(link), 'lxml')
list_a = soup_href.find_all('a', class_='styles_poster__gJgwz styles_root__wgbNq')
link_list = ['https://www.kinopoisk.ru/'+ link.get('href') for link in list_a]
```