# Помогите исправить ошибку с библиотекой BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
link = soup.find('div', class_='styles_root__ti07r').find('a', class_='styles_poster__gJgwz styles_root__wgbNq').get('href')
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
link = soup.find('div', class_='styles_root__ti07r').find('a', class_='styles_poster__gJgwz styles_root__wgbNq').get('href')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Значит этот `soup.find('div', class_='styles_root__ti07r'` вернул `None`, т.к. не смог найти тот элемент. Проверьте `r.text` или `soup` - наверняка в них или нет того тега, или он может иметь другой класс. Запустил ваш код `print(link)` вернул `/film/435/`, возможно, вы попали на защиту от ботов

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите исправить ошибку с библиотекой BeautifulSoup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1483126/Помогите-исправить-ошибку-с-библиотекой-beautifulsoup). На будущее, лучше редактировать и дополнять свой вопрос, а не создавать [новый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1483126/Помогите-исправить-ошибку-с-библиотекой-beautifulsoup) по той же проблеме, но с новой ошибкой. Сейчас есть смысл оставить более новый, т.к. там дам принятый ответ.